# Morphism is a retraction of another morphism?

Tags: homotopy-theory

I have to use definition that morphism f is retraction of morphism g, but I don't know how to represent it. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Ah, this is related to your other question I just answered. The terminology isn't so good, because Hew's answer would be right most of the time, but in the context of model categories $f$ is a retraction of $g$ if it's a retract of $g$ in the category who objects are *arrows* in the original category $\mathcal{C}$ and whose morphisms are commutative squares. This is the diagram expressing the same information:
$$\begin{matrix} A&\stackrel{i}{\to}&B&\stackrel{r}{\to}&A\\f\downarrow&&g\downarrow&&f\downarrow\\A'&\stackrel{j}{\longrightarrow}&B'&\stackrel{t}{\longrightarrow}&A'\end{matrix}$$
If $ri=1_A$ and $tj=1_{A'}$, we say $f$ is a retraction of $g.$

Answer (score 0):

"$f$ is a retraction of $g$" probably just means that $fg = 1$ in your category, whatever that category is.  I don't know what you mean by "how to represent it".  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm using slice category, I'm not sure how diagram looks like when f is retraction of g. Actually, I have to prove that slice category is Quillen model category by checking axioms and my stuck with retract axiom.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with model categories.  I'm sure someone around here is, though.  I suggest you edit your question and its title to make it more specific, and maybe add a category-theory tag.  Also, I see the Wikipedia article on model categories has a very specific diagram describing the retract axiom, so maybe that will help.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I see your point, @Graphth.  I thought dandan was having trouble applying the general definition of retraction, but now we know the story is more complicated.